# Trying to add a third servo

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pi, servo, thonny

I have a program that activates two servos. Right now, the code activates servo 'A', then servo 'B', then repeats this on a loop. I want to add a third servo, servo 'C', and I want to set it up so they run after 'A' and 'B' have looped twice. So the order would be: 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' 'C' then it would loop. Right now the servos only run in the pattern of 'A' 'B' 'A' 'B' on a loop. I am stuck and can't seem to figure out how to make this happen. Any ideas?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

aServoPin = 11
bServoPin = 13
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(aServoPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(bServoPin, GPIO.OUT)

aPwm = GPIO.PWM(aServoPin, 50)
bPwm = GPIO.PWM(bServoPin, 50)
aPwm.start(5)
bPwm.start(5)

while True:
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while(a < 5):
        for i in range(45, 135):
            position = 1./18.*(i)+2
            aPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
            time.sleep(0.005)

        for i in range(135, 45, -1):
            position = 1./18.*(i)+2
            aPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
            time.sleep(0.005)
        a = a + 1

    while(b < 5):
        for i in range(135, 45, -1):
            position = 1./18.*(i)+2
            bPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
            time.sleep(0.005)

        for i in range(45, 135):
            position = 1./18.*(i)+2
            bPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
            time.sleep(0.005)
        b = b + 1

    time.sleep(1)
aPwm.stop()
bPwm.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
while True:
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    loopAB = 0
    while(loopAB < 2):
        while(a < 5):
            for i in range(45, 135):
                position = 1./18.*(i)+2
                aPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
                time.sleep(0.005)

            for i in range(135, 45, -1):
                position = 1./18.*(i)+2
                aPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
                time.sleep(0.005)
            a = a + 1

        while(b < 5):
            for i in range(135, 45, -1):
                position = 1./18.*(i)+2
                bPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
                time.sleep(0.005)

            for i in range(45, 135):
                position = 1./18.*(i)+2
                bPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(position)
                time.sleep(0.005)
            b = b + 1
        loopAB += 1
        
    while(c < 5):
        # do some things
        c = c + 1

    time.sleep(1)
aPwm.stop()
bPwm.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```